# How to get mouse position at mouse click - Python Gtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I am writing an school project about Graph Theory. I need to implement some Graph algorithms (Dijkstra's, Prim's etc.). After that I need to visualize them in the same program.

I can draw rectangles and line inside a drawing area for visualizing graph. But I need to handle mouse events for make it interactive.

For example when user wanted to add a vertex to the graph, I need the position of mouse.

My native is not English. I couldn't explain my problem great. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `gtk.EventBox` and event'ss `x` and `y` fields:

```
import gtk

win  = gtk.Window ()
box  = gtk.EventBox ()
area = gtk.DrawingArea ()

def onclick (box, event):
   print event.x, event.y

box.connect ('button-press-event', onclick)

box.add (area)
win.add (box)
win.show_all ()
win.connect ('destroy', lambda *x: gtk.main_quit ())

gtk.main ()
```

Comment: I don't see why you would need an eventbox here, drawingarea can capture mouse events by itself.

Comment: @ergosys: Probably you are right. It seems by default it doesn't, I think there was some function to enable event capturing. If you remember what it was, please edit the answer.

Comment: ergosys, doublep's example is much more useful than your additional remark simply because he showed a working example as-is. In many cases users probably have "standard" gtk-widgets. For example, I adapted his example for ruby-gtk to show a simple hello-world label that is clickable (and also get the x and y coordinates; I actually need that for a GUI wrapper over imagemagick, so that I can finally abandon GIMP). With Gtk::DrawingArea everything is possible too but more cumbersome code-wise. So the above is a good, simple example really - absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well using vala. I did use Gtk.Layout instead of Gtk.DrawingArea.
This example also shows how to detect double clicks.

```
public class MyApp : Gtk.Application {
    public MyApp () {
    }

    protected override void activate () {

        var window = new Gtk.Window ();
        window.set_default_size (300, 400);

        var layout = new Gtk.Layout();
        layout.add (new Gtk.Label ("hello"));

        var eventbox = new Gtk.EventBox();
        eventbox.button_press_event.connect ((event) => {
            var type = event.type;
            string position = event.x.to_string() + "; " + event.y.to_string();
            if (type == Gdk.EventType.2BUTTON_PRESS) {
                print (position + " (Double click)" + "\n");
                return true;
            }
            print (position + "\n");
            return true;
        });
        eventbox.add (layout);
        window.add (eventbox);
        window.show_all ();

        add_window (window);

    }

    public static int main (string[] args) {
        return new MyApp ().run (args);
    }
}
```

compile the code `valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 <file>.vala`

execute `./<file>`